# problem in functional analysis

Tags: functional-analysis

Let X be a normed space, $0<\theta<1$ and $A \subset B_X$ ($B_X$ is the ball of radius 1 in X). For all $x\in B_X$ there exists $a \in A$ such that $\|x-a\| <\theta$.
What I have to show is that for all $x\in B_X$ there exist $a_n\in A$, $n\in \mathbb N$ such that 
$$x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\theta^n a_n.$$
Can anyone help me please?

Comment: This is not true if you take $A=\{0\}$ and $\theta =\frac{1}{2} .$

Comment: The fact that for all $x\in B_X$ there exists $a\in A$ such that $\|x−a\|<\theta$ is our hypothesis.

Answer (score 0):

Fix $x \in B_X$. Choose $a_0 \in A$ so that $\|x-a_0\|<\theta$. Now, assume that for some $n\geq0$, we have chosen elements $a_0,\ldots,a_n \in A$ so that 
$$ \left\|x-\sum_{k=0}^n\theta^ka_k\right\| < \theta^{n+1}.\qquad\qquad(*)$$
(Note that we have already done this for $n=0$). Then, $y :=\theta^{-n-1}\left(x-\sum_{k=0}^n\theta^ka_k\right)$ is an element of $B_X$ (i.e. $\|y\| < 1$) and therefore, we can choose $a_{n+1} \in A$ so that $\|y-a_{n+1}\| < \theta$. Multiplying both sides of the last inequality by $\theta^{n+1}$, we obtain a relation analogous to $(*)$, with $n$ replaced by $(n+1)$. Thus, we obtain an infinite sequence $(a_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ satisfying $(*)$ for all $n\geq0$. Since $\theta^{n+1} \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$, we conclude that the series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \theta^ka_k$ converges to $x$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was really troubled but that seems right!

Comment: You're welcome.